# offline_access token error The session is invalid because the user logged out

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-oauth

I am getting this error with the php sdk for facebook :
Fatal error: Uncaught OAuthException: Error validating access token: The session is invalid because the user logged out. thrown in /public_html/facebook/base_facebook.php on line 1106

I have already requested offline_access permission from the app and tested it with a real facebook account. it works when the account is logged in as it should, but when I log out with the facebook account, the token becomes invalid. Doesn't the offline_access permission allow access even when the user logged out?

Answer (score 1):

Facebook has recently deprecated offline_access so check your apps settings to make sure you have it enabled (although it will be gone for good in May)

Answer (score -1):

There is a problem in using offline_access as the access token expires earlier than it will be.

Refer this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/241373692605971/?browse=search_4f24f833cf6b40a21061513)